# Adding object to IList<T> throws ArrayTypeMismatchException

Tags: c#, exception

I have an `IList<IHtmlString>` to which I want to add some elements. Since short time it throws an `ArrayTypeMismatchException`, but I have no idea why. This also happens when adding or accessing elements from HttpSessionStateBase.

```
public class HtmlList 
{
  private IList<IHtmlString> _listItems = new List<IHtmlString>();

  public void Add(IHtmlString listItem)
  {
    if (listItem != null)
    {
      _listItems.Add(listItem); // here ArrayTypeMismatchException is thrown
    }
  }
}
```

Can anybody explain this to me? And why didn't it happen during the last three years? I got the exception the first time after changing from .NET 4.0 to 4.5.

Stack Trace:

> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
>      at MyCompany.Web.Mvc.UI.HtmlList.Add(IHtmlString element)
>      at MyCompany.Web.Mvc.Models.CaptchaExtensions.CaptchaImageElement.ToString()
>      at MyCompany.Web.Mvc.Models.CaptchaExtensions.CaptchaImageElement.Render(Int32 width, Int32 height)
>      at ASP.views_teilnahme_index_aspx.__RenderContent3(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: That sounds very odd to me. Can you reproduce it with a short but *complete* example?

Comment: Could this be polymorphism rearing it's head? Post the calling code?

Comment: you could also try looking for anything in your code that touches _listItems - maybe something overwrites it with something different than List<>. You could also spot that by adding `readonly` modifier to the field (assuming your code does not require setting it)

Comment: Please post the full stack-trace of the exception.

Comment: @Knaģis: How would a new instance make a difference? It still would be of type `IList<IHtmlString>`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - if that new instance is not List<> then it might be something completely different (e.g. a custom class) that is doing something else and then throwing the exception. without a full stack trace it is hard to say.

Comment: I just watching serial upvotes to _uncompleted_ question..

Comment: @SonerGönül yes its interesting to see how many upvotes this question gets. The provided code cannot throw such an exception.

Comment: @Knaģis But you can not assign something other than `IList<IHtmlString>` to `list` without getting an exception.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: That's correct, but he still has a point. `IList<IHtmlString>` can be implemented by some other class beside `List<IHtmlString>`. And that other class might throw that exception inside the `Add` method.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth This is true - didn't consider that.

Comment: Actually, it's not a field but a property: `public IList<IHtmlString> Content { get; private set; }` and it's initialized with an `new List<IHtmlString>()` in the constructor only.

Comment: can you post the code when you override MyCompany.Web.Mvc.Models.CaptchaExtensions.CaptchaImageElement.ToString() method , Overridden ToString()

Comment: which version of MVC are you using

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming that IHtmlString is defined in the System.Web namespace.

this should not happen until you have `IHtmlString` interface defined somewhere else in your code and you are implementing a class with your `IHtmlString` interface and adding it to list

Please check this ,

Comment: It's `System.Web.IHtmlString`

Comment: compiler would not let such code compile - the method Add could not be invoked.